# is it possible to have dynamic struct members dependent to another member in c#

Tags: c#, dynamic, struct, member

in this case a binary file is written with the file format based on a struct

```
    struct fileformat
    {
         struct mask
         {
                bool mem1present
                bool mem2present
                bool mem3present
                //5 bits unused
          }
          //member only written in file if mem1present is true
          byte mem1present
          //member only written in file if mem2present is true
          byte mem1present
          //member only written in file if mem3present is true
          byte mem1present
    }
```

is this possible to be implemented in c#

Comment: What are you using to write the structure to the file?

Comment: i have already tried writing everything but if it does not dynamically change you cannot marshall the data correctly. so the questions remains is it even possible or am i just wasting my time. i did not write the file myself i am only taking the data out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure - you have to implement the serialization yourself to some extent, but you can do that easily enough.

It's unclear what sort of serialization you're using - if you're using the "raw" binary serialization from .NET, you want to override `GetObjectData` to only add the relevant data on serialization, and then in the protected constructor taking a `SerializationInfo` and a `StreamingContext`, populate your struct from the same data in reverse. See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973893.aspx) for some details.

I don't know what happens if you're using XML serialization.

If you're writing your *own* serialization (i.e. you've got a method such as `WriteToStream`) then you can choose to represent it however you want, of course.

EDIT: It sounds like you've probably got an existing file format you need to read in, but you can define your own types. It's easy to have a class or struct with multiple members and *possibly* a mask to say what's set, although without knowing more it may not be the best design. While you *can* use explicit layout to make this efficient in memory, it's probably easiest just to have separate members:

```
struct Foo
{
    // Bit-set to determine which fields are actually used
    private readonly byte mask;

    private readonly int value1;
    private readonly int value2;
    private readonly int value3;

    public Foo(byte mask, int value1, int value2, int value3)
    {
        this.mask = mask;
        this.value1 = value1;
        this.value2 = value2;
        this.value3 = value3;
    }
}
```

Then somewhere (either in the data type or not), something like:

```
Foo ReadFoo(Stream stream)
{
    byte mask = stream.ReadByte();
    int value1 = 0, value2 = 0, value3 = 0;
    if ((mask & 1) == 1)
    {
       // However you do that, depending on your file format
        value1 = ReadInt32FromStream(stream); 
    }
    if ((mask & 2) == 2)
    {
       // However you do that, depending on your file format
        value2 = ReadInt32FromStream(stream); 
    }
    if ((mask & 4) == 4)
    {
       // However you do that, depending on your file format
        value3 = ReadInt32FromStream(stream); 
    }
    return new Foo(mask, value1, value2, value3);
}
```

By the way, I would seriously consider whether a struct is *really* the best approach here - consider using a class instead. I very rarely create my own structs.

Comment: im not actually using any serialization, im just reading one of the bytes from the data which tells its data length and then use Marshall.ptrStructure an array of bytes with the start to the data length. thou i am having trouble implementing the sudo code above in c# since it is some how dynamic.

Comment: @michael: Well you won't be able to use `Marshal.PtrToStructure`... you should write the code explicitly to read/write bytes from/to the stream. It's unclear whether it's just the IO that you're having problems with, or the fundamental layout of the struct. (Is there any reason it's a struct rather than a class, btw?)

Comment: yes i think Marshal.PtrToStructure cannot be used in my case because of the dynamics. the IO is no problem its just that im working out if the fundamental layout of the struct is even possible. no reason really. it is just that im trying to discover how the hell they did that in the first place. i guess they implemented it explicitly as well.

Comment: @michael: Who is "they" in this case? You need to separate the concepts of file layout and memory layout... will edit.

Comment: fin guys. yes that is what i did not understand completely i guess. memory layout will be as complete as it gets. while during file layout they do something radical to save spaces needed. thanks jon.

Answer (score 0):

Note: Your sample shows only the declaration of a nested struct type, not an instance of it.

From your question wording, you need an instance member.

```
struct fileformat 
{ 
     struct mask  // type declaration only
     { 
            bool mem1present 
            bool mem2present 
            bool mem3present 
            //5 bits unused 
      } 

      public mask mask;    // <-- Member instance here
}
```

I apologize if I've misunderstood. Perhaps your struct was only to communicate the structure of the file to us?